# How to set width of ngb Dropdown Menu inherited from parent ngb Dropdown append to body?

Tags: html, angular, ng-bootstrap

Since I have to use property

```
container="body"
```

->
https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1012

My dropdown is attached to the body(correct me if i'm wrong...). 

So it means I can't inherit width from parent (ngbDropdown)-> ngbDropdownMenu. 

How I can set the same width for dropdown menu and button??

[NgbDropdown with width: inherit but without property container="body"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6REK.png)

[ngbDropdown with width: inherit but with property container="body"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FM0G.png)

So I need property container="body"
but still want to inherit width from button

Comment: very difficult to understand the question as it is - can you provide a MVC example?

Comment: Images attached

Answer (score 2):

I have the solution for this!  It is a combination of a few techniques.  I added some Typescript code that listens for the `openChange` event emitted by the Dropdown.  At that time I grab the width of the `hostElement` which is the Dropdown's trigger.  I use that to set the width of the `.dropdown` that was appended to body.  Now, my CSS will work which sets `.dropdown-menu` width to 100%.  Unfortunately this causes a brief flash where the user can see the dropdown at the normal width before it changes to 100% of the trigger's width.  To fix that I use some CSS to control the opacity of the `.dropdown-menu`.

1) Hook the `(openChange)` event of ngbDropdown:

```html
<div
    ngbDropdown #dropdown="ngbDropdown" container="body"
    #hostElement (openChange)="fixDropdownWidth(hostElement)">
```

I am using a Template Variable to grab a reference to the `hostElement` and I pass that element as a parameter to my function `fixDropdownWidth()` in my Component:

2) Fix function of Component:

```
    fixDropdownWidth(hostElement: HTMLDivElement) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let bodyDD: HTMLDivElement[] = <HTMLDivElement[]>Array.from(this._document.body.children).filter((child: HTMLDivElement) => child.className.indexOf('dropdown') >= 0);
            if (bodyDD && bodyDD.length) {
                this._renderer.setStyle(bodyDD[0], 'width', hostElement.clientWidth + 'px');
                this._renderer.addClass(bodyDD[0].children[0], 'fixed');
            }
        }, 0);
    }
```

I must use `setTimeout()` here because `.dropdown` is actually not yet added to DOM.

3) This is using Angular Renderer2 which needs to be injected to your constructor along with Angular `@DOCUMENT`:

```
    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any, private _renderer: Renderer2) { }
```

You will need to add some `import`s to your Component for these:

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
```

4) Final piece of the puzzle is the CSS which makes `.dropdown-menu` opacity 0 by default, until the width has been "fixed".  See here also the `min-width: 100%` which is making the dropdown the same width as the trigger with CSS.

```
body > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
    &.fixed {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

All together now, what happened?

1. We tapped into the openChange event emitted by ngbDropdown.
2. At that time we grabbed the hostElement's width and set the `.dropdown-menu`'s container `.dropdown` to have the same width, that way our CSS rule of `min-width: 100%` will work
3. Because the `dropdown-menu` briefly flashes we turned the opacity to zero.
4. In our fix routine we set a class of "fixed" which reveals the dropdown with `opacity: 1` after the width has been set correctly.

Final thing to mention is I added a Github issue for this:
https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/3523
Requested to have the ng-bootstrap framework set hostElement's width so we won't have to do this workaround.